# Ignoring characters after backslash "\" - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have an application where I need to split the string with "," but I want to  Ignore `"\,"` `("\\,")`.

Is there any one line solution?

sample input :- `"This is first\\, this is still first, this is second"`

sample output :- `["This is first, this is still first", " this is second"]`

Comment: Can you provide sample input and sample output?

Comment: @dvo added sample input output.

Comment: If there's some character that can never appear in the string, you can replace `\,` with it, split the string, then replace that character with `,` in all the results.

Comment: @Barmar The input is completely dependent on user they can input anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a negative look-behind regexp, this could work:

```js
const input = "This is first \\, this is still first, this is second";
// Split on all commas that aren't preceded by a backslash.
const result = input.split( /(?<!\\),/ );
console.log( result );
```

Just `.map()` with `.trim()` if you do not want the leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a character sequence that can never appear in the original string, you can replace all the `\,` with it, split the string, then undo the replacement.

```js
let input = "This is first \\, this is still first, this is second";
let output = input.replace(/\\,/g, '-comma-').split(',').map(s => s.replace(/-comma-/g, ','));
console.log(output);
```

This isn't a perfect solution if the input is user-generated, since they could type `-comma-`, but you can make that replacement string arbitrarily complex so it will be improbable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.*?[^\\]+?(?:,|$)
```

[image]

---

```js
let splitByComma = (str) =>
  str.match(/.*?[^\\]+?(?:,|$)/g).map(v => v.replace(/(\\,)|,$/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? ',' : ''))

console.log(splitByComma('\\, some, more some\\123'))
console.log(splitByComma("This is first \\, this is still first, this is second"))
console.log(splitByComma("hello\\,123, some text"))
console.log(splitByComma("\\,\\,\\,123, 123-123\\,1232,"))
```